# Python re.findall between two strings while excluding strings

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

My current code is the following:

```
idk = {"id":30511879634,"title":"3.5y","option1":"3.5y","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":{"id":18778730002,"product_id":8876555346,"position":1,"created_at":"2017-02-15T15:51:03-05:00","updated_at":"2017-02-15T15:51:37-05:00","src":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/1527\/4931\/products\/AJ6_HEIRESS_PRODUCT.jpg?v=1487191897","variant_ids":[30511879634,30511879698,30511879762,30511879826,30511879890,30511879954,30511880018,30511880082]},"available":false,"name":"Air Jordan 6 Retro Premium GG 'Heiress' - 3.5y","public_title":"3.5y","options":["3.5y"],"price":16000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":null,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":""},{"id":30511879698,"title":"4y","option1":"4y","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":{"id":18778730002,"product_id":8876555346,"position":1,"created_at":"2017-02-15T15:51:03-05:00","updated_at":"2017-02-15T15:51:37-05:00","src":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/1527\/4931\/products\/AJ6_HEIRESS_PRODUCT.jpg?v=1487191897","variant_ids":[30511879634,30511879698,30511879762,30511879826,30511879890,30511879954,30511880018,30511880082]},"available":true,"name":"Air Jordan 6 Retro Premium GG 'Heiress' - 4y","public_title":"4y","options":["4y"],"price":16000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":""},
variants = re.findall(r'"id":(.*?),"title"', idk)
```

which returns `['30511879634', '18778730002,"product_id":8876555346,"position":1,"created_at":"2017-02-15T15:51:03-05:00","updated_at":"2017-02-15T15:51:37-05:00","src":"https:\\/\\/cdn.shopify.com\\/s\\/files\\/1\\/1527\\/4931\\/products\\/AJ6_HEIRESS_PRODUCT.jpg?v=1487191897","variant_ids":[30511879634,30511879698,30511879762,30511879826,30511879890,30511879954,30511880018,30511880082]},"available":false,"name":"Air Jordan 6 Retro Premium GG \'Heiress\' - 3.5y","public_title":"3.5y","options":["3.5y"],"price":16000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":null,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":""},{"id":30511879698']`

but I want it to return `['30511879634', '30511879698']`

I know I can do `variants = re.findall(r'"id":[^"product_id"].,"title"', idk)` but that would return `['"id":30511879634,"title"', '"id":30511879698,"title"']`

I've tried `variants = re.findall(r'"id":[^"product_id"](.*?),"title"', idk)` but that doesn't work. Is there anyway I can return just the numbers while making sure the second id (18778730002) is not included in the list, rather just 30511879634 and 30511879698.

Comment: Well, First of all it's hard to read, Please post only relevant portions

Comment: Any particular reason you aren't treating this as a regular dictionary? It seems like it's a standard Python dictionary?

Comment: This seems to be some `json` response so why note use the appropriate module?

Comment: @ZdaR my apologies...didn't want to leave anything out in case it was needed for a solution...in reality the text portion is much larger I tried shortening it to where one could see one repetition of the pattern

Comment: @idjaw the text portion is much larger than what I have posted and I reuse the text to find other patterns within it...considering that, re.findall seemed appropriate in my mind

Comment: @DanteArcese But based on the structure you are providing this seems like standard 'json' as mentioned by someone else. Why not use the available tools to actually parse through this properly?

Comment: @idjaw I am unfamiliar with such tools as I am fairly new to Python and coding in general (as this is my first language) so I use what I know to do what I need to do...I will look into json handling for future reference

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use this *regex* ...

```
(?<=\"id\":)\d+(?=,\"title\")
```

see **[regex demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/J8Di6H/1)**

**python** ( [demo](https://ideone.com/vyEmv4) )

```
import re

idk = """{"id":30511879634,"title":"3.5y","option1":"3.5y","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":{"id":18778730002,"product_id":8876555346,"position":1,"created_at":"2017-02-15T15:51:03-05:00","updated_at":"2017-02-15T15:51:37-05:00","src":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/1527\/4931\/products\/AJ6_HEIRESS_PRODUCT.jpg?v=1487191897","variant_ids":[30511879634,30511879698,30511879762,30511879826,30511879890,30511879954,30511880018,30511880082]},"available":false,"name":"Air Jordan 6 Retro Premium GG 'Heiress' - 3.5y","public_title":"3.5y","options":["3.5y"],"price":16000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":null,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":""},{"id":30511879698,"title":"4y","option1":"4y","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":{"id":18778730002,"product_id":8876555346,"position":1,"created_at":"2017-02-15T15:51:03-05:00","updated_at":"2017-02-15T15:51:37-05:00","src":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/1527\/4931\/products\/AJ6_HEIRESS_PRODUCT.jpg?v=1487191897","variant_ids":[30511879634,30511879698,30511879762,30511879826,30511879890,30511879954,30511880018,30511880082]},"available":true,"name":"Air Jordan 6 Retro Premium GG 'Heiress' - 4y","public_title":"4y","options":["4y"],"price":16000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":null,"inventory_quantity":1,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":""}"""
variants = re.findall(r"(?<=\"id\":)\d+(?=,\"title\")", idk)
print(variants) #-> ['30511879634', '30511879698']
```

Comment: This seems very hacky - why not use a `json` parser instead?

Comment: @Jan coz OP didn't ask for it :P

Comment: @siam and that's why I love your answer ;)